# far from the worst

Tags: grammar

*It was far from the worst movie I've watched in the last 25 years.*

I am not sure whether this sentence means:

1. The movie was definitely the worst I have watched in the last 25 years.
2. Although the movie was bad, there are even worse ones that I have watched.

Comment: A form of understatement. The movie was decent, enjoyable, but not of the highest quality or the most entertaining.

Comment: Or 'damning with faint praise'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 2nd sentence, "*...there are even worse ones that I have watched*" is what is meant by the expression "*far from the worst*".

Comment: Yes, this would be implying that while the subject in question wasn't that enjoyable, there have been much worse things in comparison.